# How to add a process to sandboxd's configuration?

Tags: macos, security, sandbox

I have a particular process that is having some problems writing to the `/private/tmp` folder.  `sandboxd` keeps emitting the following error:

```
sandboxd[xxx] ([xxxxx]): process(xxxxx) deny file-write-create /private/tmp/blah.ext
```

I would like to understand how to set up my own `sandboxd` rules either via `sandboxd`'s config file or by creating a new file with the permissions in it.